# How would I dynamically select a certain Object depending on user input then use other Methods to alter that particular Object?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm currently writing a Virtual Pet style app, I have created a Class for the base of the pets called Pet.class

```
    package com.grim.droidchi;

public class Pet {

    public static int Health = 100;
    public static int Happiness = 10;
    public static int Level = 1;
    public static int Hunger = 0;
    public static int Exp = 0;
    public static String Name;
    public static Boolean isAlive = true;
    public static Boolean isSick = false;

    public Pet(int startHealth, int startLevel, int startHunger) {

    }

   }
```

And a 'Dog' class which extends the base pet class

```
package com.grim.droidchi;


public class Dog extends Pet {

    public Dog(int startHealth, int startLevel, int startHunger) {
        super(startHealth, startLevel, startHunger);

    }

}
```

every 30 minutes An AlarmManager triggers my Gameloop.class

```
package com.grim.droidchi;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Gameloop extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    private static final String TAG = "VPET";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loop running");
        if (Pet.isAlive == true) {
            Pet.Hunger = Pet.Hunger + 1;
            Pet.Exp = Pet.Exp + 2;
            Pet.Happiness = Pet.Happiness - 1;

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);
            mp.start();
            petLevel();
            petStatus();
            randomEncounters();
        } else {

        }
    }

    private void petLevel() {


    }

    private void randomEncounters() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.20) {
            Pet.isSick = true; 

        }

    }

    private void petStatus() {
        if (Pet.Hunger > 7) {
            Pet.isAlive = false;

        } 

    }

}
```

How do I get what's done in the Gameloop to be dependent on which particular pet the user decides to pick? (Assuming I create more pet types. )

P.S Also as a siden ote to this question, What is the best way to implement keeping the UI always up-to-date from the Gameloop class?

Any help will be appreciated. I am still learning about Java and Android sometimes its hard to find a specific/question answer even a midst of all good learning materials.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For type of pet:

```
if (pet instanceof Dog)
```

To update the UI, define an Interface.  See my answer here:

[Accessing R from a BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029647/accessing-r-from-a-broadcastreceiver/15029963#15029963)

It's for a different scenario but easily adapted.

[EDIT]

`instanceof` is often a sign of a poor design.

Try this:

```
public void feed(Pet pet, int foodAmount){
        pet.feed(foodAmount);
}

public class Pet{       
}

public class Dog extends Pet{
    public void feed(int foodAmount){
        // feed like a dog
    }
}


public class Cat extends Pet{
    public void feed(int foodAmount){
        // feed like a cat
    }
}
```

Then just use `pet.feed(10);`

Comment: Using instanceof, really?  That should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.  Inheritance is a better answer here.

Comment: Thank you, I think you answered another question I've not asked yet haha, I meant for example If I had Dog, Horse, Fish, Bigfoot as choices, and the user picks Bigfoot how would I get the gameloop to then the onReceive with the Bigfoot object? Or would I just have lots of if statements in my Gameloop? 

I've actually already (thank you again I do get the idea of it) seen your other answer but its a actually little intimidating to try work out how to adapt that for my situation having not much experience aside from what I learn and what you lovely lot teach.

Comment: What Gabe means is that instanceof works fine but it's often "papering over the cracks".  Better to use overloaded methods,  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Read my answer to using an Interface again.  It's *really* simple to adapt.  In fact, you probably only need to change the arguments passed to the onReceived callback.

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you I'm going to accept your answer although it doesn't make sense to me yet that doesn't mean its wrong, thank you again.