# Using methods from extended BroadcastReceiver class in Android

Tags: android, get, broadcastreceiver

I created a class - extending `BroadcastReceiver` , whenever the 'event' happens the class "stamps" the  local time on private members in the class, and i want to get this time of occurrence,
since the event is raised and i cant get this stamp as returned value I thought about using the class members and create get() methods  for each, the problem is i can't seem to call any of the getter's i created.

Comment: Define an `Interface` and implement it in the receiver and the class(es) where you want the time stamp.  Pass the time stamp as a parameter to the interface callback.

Comment: Can you please expand you answer ? what is the Interface you are talking about ? any examples / references ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029647/accessing-r-from-a-broadcastreceiver/15029963#15029963