# How to Pass Value from BroadcastReceiver to Another Activity

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I almost give up after several hours of thinking on how I can pass a value from BroadcastReceiver to Another Activity.

Here's the code I currently have on my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
       if (extras == null)
       return;

       Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
       for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
          SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
          String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
          String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

         // A custom Intent that will used as another Broadcast
         Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").
         putExtra("get_msg", sender+":"+body);

         // To display a Toast whenever there is an SMS.
         Toast.makeText(context,body,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         //You can place your check conditions here(on the SMS or the sender)            
         //and then send another broadcast 
         context.sendBroadcast(in);

        // This is used to abort the broadcast and can be used to silently
        // process incoming message and prevent it from further being 
        // broadcasted. Avoid this, as this is not the way to program an app.
        this.abortBroadcast();
        }
     }
 }
```

And this is the code of SMSReceiverActivity class:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SMSReceiverActivity extends ListActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsreceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");
        mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");

            //Process the sms format and extract body &amp; phoneNumber
            msg = msg.replace("\n", "");
            String body = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf(":")+1, msg.length());
            String pNumber = msg.substring(0,msg.lastIndexOf(":"));

            //Add it to the list or do whatever you wish to
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            text.setText(body);
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mIntentReceiver);
    }

}
```

I have also defined the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.smsTest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SMSTest"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SMSReceiverActivity"></activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

I have followed closely the tutorial I have found at [this link](http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/receive-sms-using-android-broadcastreceiver-inside-an-activity/).

It says there that "We declare a BroadcastReciever in the class itself rather than the manifest in the onResume() method so that when the app returns in the foreground , it should receive the SMS."

I assumed that "SMSReceiverActivity" will receive a message from SmsReceiver (i.e. BroadcastReceiver) if it is active. I tried creating a button to open SMSReceiverActivity from my SMSTest.java as shown below:

```
btnMsgRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SMSReceiverActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

});
```

but when I click the button the apps crashes.

I would be very greatful if somebody can help me on this. How can I pass the value from BroadcastReceiver to SMSReceiverActivity.java as new Activity.

Thank you

UPDATE:

Here's the logcat after I click the "Open SMS Receiver" button:

```
04-07 11:38:16.878: D/AndroidRuntime(5269): Shutting down VM
04-07 11:38:16.878: W/dalvikvm(5269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smsTest/com.example.smsTest.SMSReceiverActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at com.example.smsTest.SMSReceiverActivity.onCreate(SMSReceiverActivity.java:17)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-07 11:38:16.908: E/AndroidRuntime(5269):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You could adapt my answer to this question, and perhaps upvote it if it helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029647/accessing-r-from-a-broadcastreceiver/15029963#15029963

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in log:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.list'

means you will need to change `ListView` id to `android:id="@android:id/list"` in `activity_smsreceiver` layout if you are extending `ListActivity`

Comment: hi, thank you very much. i'm almost there. i can now set the value from `BroadcastReceiver` to `SMSReceiverActivity`. now how can I display the value to ListView instead of text view. how can i change this line: `TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
text.setText(body);` sorry for noob question.

Comment: @jaypabs:now you are getting value in textview or not?

Comment: yes, i am getting a value to the textview now. what i want now is to append every message it receives from BroadcastReceiver to listview instead of text view. can u help me please?

Comment: @jaypabs: sure, try to change your [code as](http://pastebin.com/9rw8Fj1R) to show data in listView

Comment: the value does not go to listview. it is showing in text view. please see my activity_smsreceiver.xml if it is correct. here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/XtBsjUsC)

Comment: @jaypabs : sorry, plz add `listview.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);` line after `rrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SMSReceiverActivity.this,...)` line because i forget to add it

Comment: thank you. but the problem is it does not append. the previous message is gone after a new message arrives. how to retain the old message?

Comment: @jaypabs : it depend on your current logic. if you want to show old message then store messages in SharedPreferences and call `arrayAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged()`. thanks if my answer help you in solving current issue then accept it and make new question for other issues if you are facing